# JQuery conflicts causing the page not to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working in a big wordpress page.  I try to add some tracking script, so, i just include jquery library as first step

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and then the page stop loading on 20% from top.

The error in console is showing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ultimate_video_bg is not a
 function(anonymous function) @ ultimate.min.js:34m.Callbacks.j @
 jquery.js:2m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:2m.extend.ready @
 jquery.js:2J @ jquery.js:2
```

Now, i need to import jquery library for my 4 line script and it should not conflict with other scripts.

Please help me.

Comment: what have you tried so far, it would be better if you put your code here or on fiddle.

Comment: When i removed the jquery library file it is working fine..

Comment: that simply means, your jquery is conflicting with other one, better you should use noconflict function, it is a broad, it would be better is you post your code here,

Comment: You say that you are using a wordpress page any plugins working on that page as well? maybe if you disable one by one you can get a better idea where the conflict is occurring.

Comment: I said its large wordpress page and i also allowed to post 4 to 5 lines tracking script.  and i did by placing the script in footer and it is not best practice.  but, still waiting for to avoid conflicts, so that i can make the script run only in 1 page and not in all the pages by adding it in footer